# "File not Found" Error while using "With Open" and absolute path with Python

Tags: python, directory, with-statement

I am developing a simple webservice with Python/Flask.

I have this code that should write to a config file located one step down from my root directory where I am running the program:

```
config_file_path = abspath("text_files\config.txt")
    with open(config_file_path, 'w') as txt:
        txt.write(f"{report_input}: {record_input}")
```

But I get an error that says:

```
  File "C:\Users\Tech4\Desktop\python_server_test\server.py", line 26, in form_post
    with open(config_file_path, 'w') as txt:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Tech4\\text_files\\config.txt'
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Does the folder C:\Users\Tech4\text_files\ exist already?

Comment: Did you make sure that the current working directory is what you expect it to be? Are you sure that you want to write to a file named `config.txt` that is inside a folder named `text_files`, which is **directly inside** your personal user directory (**not** on the Desktop)? Because that's where the error message says it is trying to write. This fails when the folder does not already exist; please see the linked duplicate for details. You should also [beware of backslashes in Windows paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953834).